# Add post overwriting permalink from previous post in 4.6

Tags: permalinks, database, server, bug

Since updating to 4.6, I've noticed that if I add a second post shortly after the first, I'm overwriting the first post. The editor is blank, but permalink is the pre-existing post.

I simply have no idea if this is a database issue, server issue, or what. I've turned off W3TC caching and it doesn't seem to fix it.

Anyone else experiencing this? Where can I look to debug? There doesn't seem to be anything in the php logs.

See screenshot:

[image: error screenshot permalink]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a caching issue, though there isn't a single cause for it. There is still ongoing discussion, as well as multiple suggestions for fixes about this on the Wordpress issue tracker:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37889

You can fix the symptoms by ensuring pages under "/wp-admin" are never cached. If using Apache, you can do this by adding the following to your Apache configuration:

```
<LocationMatch "/wp-admin">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

You should place this after any other `Header` directive in your Apache configuration. If ensure you can put this in either:

- `.htaccess` on your project root;
- The `<VirtualHost>` section of your main Apache configuration (assuming you're using virtual hosts!)

And then check in a web browsers these headers come as expected.

For a solution fixing the issue (rather than just the symptoms) keep following the bug report above.